# Finding degree and basis for a field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I want to find the degree and basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. I can show that the degree is $3$, since $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}] = 6$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$. Intuitively, I think $\{1,\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{9}\}$ should be a basis, which means I should show that $x^3 - 3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

How do I do that?

Comment: Your basis does work. But the irreducibility of $x^3-3$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ is something you got as a by-product of the proof that the degree is $3$. If it weren't irreducible, the degree would be $<3$.

Comment: If $x^3-3$ were reducible, it would have a factor that vanishes at $\sqrt[3]{3}$, right? So then the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{3}$ would would have degree $\leq 2$. But what is stopping the minimal polynomial from having degree $2$?

Comment: If it had degree two, then consequently you would also have $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\root3\of3):\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]=2$. Contrary to what you already know.

Comment: The general fact at play is the following. If the minimal polynomial over a field $F$ of an element $\alpha$ has degree $n$, then $[F(\alpha):F]=n$. You have undoubtedly seen it applied when $F=\Bbb{Q}$, but this time it is convenient to use it with $F=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ also.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct.

A degree three polynomial is reducible if and only if it has a root. Suppose $x^3-3$ has a root $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$; then
$$
a^3+3a^2b\sqrt{2}+6ab^2+2b^3\sqrt{2}-3=0
$$
implies
$$
\begin{cases}
a^3+6ab^2=3 \\[4px]
3a^2b+2b^3=0
\end{cases}
$$
The second equation yields $b=0$ or $3a^2+2b^2=0$ and it's easy to conclude the root does not exist.

---

A proof based on dimensions is possible, too. We have
$$
n=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),\mathbb{Q}]\tag{*}
$$
so $2\mid n$; similarly
$$
n=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})]
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}),\mathbb{Q}]\tag{**}
$$
so $3\mid n$. Hence $6\mid n$. On the other hand, the two relation above show also $n\le 6$, hence $n=6$. Then (*) proves
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=3
$$
and, since $x^3-3$ has $\sqrt[3]{3}$ as root, it must be irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$: indeed it divides the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{3}$, which must have degree $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a typical diamond of fields. First determine $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{3})$ over the rationals. Verify that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=6$. This is since $x^3-3$ is irreducible by Eisenstein with $p=3$ and $x^2-2$ irreducible over the rationals as well thus,

$$\text{gcd}([\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}],[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}])=1 \Rightarrow [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=6$$
 Thus if you consider $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})$ then we must have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3}:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=3$ since we have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$; hence just apply the tower theorem.

[image]

A vector space basis is $\{1,\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt[3]{9}\}$ so your intitution was correct.

Comment: Now you can fill in the top two stems.